# Rails: Namespaced Class Method Referring to Wrong Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, class-method

I have two models, one of which is namespaced:

```
Group::Vote
```

The other of which is not:

```
Vote
```

The namespaced model has a class method:

```
def self.get_user_value(voteable)
  Group::Vote.where(:user_id => User.current.id, :voteable_type => voteable.class.name, :voteable_id => voteable.id).first.value
end
```

Strangely, when I call that method like so:

```
Group::Vote.get_user_value(item)
```

It gets sent to a similarly named class method in the `Vote` model. Am I doing something wrong or am I encountering some sort of hopeless bug?

Comment: What does your model directory structure look like? Is the Vote class in models/vote.rb and Group::Vote in models/group/vote.rb?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly how it is.